# Why does `default( None )` not always appear to produce `None`

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is there a logical reasoning that explains why the two `debug` tasks in the Ansible playbook below respectively output `"NONE"` and `"FALSE"` and not both `"NONE"`?

```
- hosts:  'all'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ foo | default( None ) | ternary( "TRUE", "FALSE", "NONE" ) }}'

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ bar | ternary( "TRUE", "FALSE", "NONE" ) }}'

  vars:

    bar: '{{ foo | default( None ) }}'
```

I observed this with `ansible@2.8.5` btw

---

*[edit@2019-10-16]*

As inferred from @VladimirBotka's answer, one could say the real "problem" is that `None` isn't transitive with respect to substitution. My use of `default(...)` was needlessly complicating matters and the example can be simplified to:

```
- hosts: 'all'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ None | ternary( "TRUE", "FALSE", "NONE" ) }}'

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ bar | ternary( "TRUE", "FALSE", "NONE" ) }}'

  vars:
    bar: '{{ None }}'
```

... and still produce the exact same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `foo|default(None)` evaluates to `null`
- `{{ foo|default(None) }}` evaluates to an empty string `""`

The task

```
- debug:
    msg: bar is empty string
  when: bar|length == 0
```

gives

```
"msg": "bar is empty string"
```

But the task

```
- debug:
    msg: foo is empty string
  when: foo|default(None)|length == 0
```

fails with the error:

```
"... object of type 'NoneType' has no len() ... "
```

As a result in ternary, an empty string will select *FALSE* and *null* will select *NONE*.

---

Notes

1) See the Note in [Omitting Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters)

2) Both `null` and  empty string `""` select *FALSE* in [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) if the third parameter is omitted. The tasks

```
   - debug:
        msg: "{{ bar|ternary('TRUE', 'FALSE') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo|default(None)|ternary('TRUE', 'FALSE') }}"
```

give

```
"msg": "FALSE"
"msg": "FALSE"
```

Comment: So, one could say the real "problem" is that `None` isn't transitive with respect to substitution. My use of `default(...)` was in fact irrelevant; the example could have been simplified to:
```
- hosts:  'all'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ None | ternary( "TRUE", "FALSE", "NONE" ) }}'
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ bar | ternary( "TRUE", "FALSE", "NONE" ) }}'
  vars:
    bar: '{{ None }}'
```

... and still produce the same output.